# How to Return Riak Objects Sorted by Key Value?

Tags: php, javascript, riak

I have a bucket called 'employees'.  In it are keys that look like this:

```
"ryan_07-01-2012_8:15pm"
"joy_07-02-2012_8:20pm"
"ryan_07-03-2012_8:30pm"
"tammy_07-05-2012_8:10pm"
"tammy_07-11-2012_8:01pm"
"joy_07-15-2012_8:20pm"
```

All of the keys point to Riak objects that look similar to this:

```
{ description: "left the office", signed-out: "8:15pm" }
```

In Riak, especially with php client, riak-php, how would you return the objects ordered by time and date based on the key values ( ie "ryan_07-01-2012_8:15pm" ).

Comment: A "bucket"? Do you mean an "array"? I don't know what Riak is, but are you asking for a PHP or a JavaScript solution? (Why tag the question with both?)

Comment: A bucket is a purely Riak term.  I tagged it as both b/c in this case a Riak php client, riak-php, is being used and Javascript is being used in the MapReduce Riak phase.

Comment: You should accept the answers provided for your previous questions, that's the least you can do for people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a better time/date format than this, that format isn't particularly formattable.  For example YYYY-MM-DD_HH:MM:SS (php's `date()` format would be `'Y-m-d_H:i:s'`).  This would be able to be sorted lexicographically.

If you HAVE to have the format indicated, you're going to have to convert that to a sortable format during sorting, so that will slow things down.

You can use key filters to limit the documents coming back to a certain range (or use a secondary index - this will be faster, see more below).  Although it's possible to sort the return values inside of a map/reduce operation, I recommend sorting the data in PHP after it comes back (using for example [`uasort()`](https://www.php.net/uasort)).  This will be less complicated than sorting in a map/reduce operation, and it's likely faster as well since you don't have to spin up a V8 javascript engine for map/reduce (assuming you're not writing Erlang M/R functions).  Also data can be reduced multiple times as nodes report in, so you essentially re-sort some data multiple times.  So sorting in PHP is easier and faster.

You should also consider adding a secondary index (or several) to the documents, this will dramatically speed up time to locate the documents.  For example, you might have a 'timestamp' secondary index, and you can search on that by range.  For documentation on secondary indexes, see the [README on the Riak PHP client](https://github.com/basho/riak-php-client#adding-secondary-indexes).  For working examples on using secondary indexes in the Riak PHP client, check out the [secondary index unit tests](https://github.com/basho/riak-php-client/blob/master/unit_tests.php#L407).